# Auto BNB to charity / marketing?

Tags: binance

I'm trying to create a charity coin that auto transfers percentages to BNB to go into the charity and marketing wallets.  I saw that Morty Token was doing this.  (https://bscscan.com/address/0xb76ec79ca2a3ecbc5f54c77bac782352c118e706#code)  However, when I tried to run that contract for myself, I noticed that EVERY sell generates an auto-sell from the Pancakeswap Router.  When I look at the Morty Token chart, this is not happening.  It's generating sells from the Pancakeswap Router, but NOT every time someone sells.  It's very spaced out.  How is this being achieved?

https://bscscan.com/address/0xb76ec79ca2a3ecbc5f54c77bac782352c118e706#code

Answer (score 0):

They have a condition in `_transfer` function to do that when the contract's token balance is above `numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity`.

```
bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
if (overMinTokenBalance && !inSwapAndLiquify && from != pancakeswapV2Pair && swapAndLiquifyEnabled) {
    contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
    //add liquidity
    swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
}
```